# Не выводятся данные из базы PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть такой код

```
<tbody><?php require ('includes/connection.php') ; ?> <?php  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM patients ") 
            or die(mysqli_error());         
             ?> 
       <?php    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result )) { ?>                                 <tr>
                                            <td><? echo (" ".$row["card_id"]." "); ?></td>
                                            <td><? echo (" ".$row["fio"]." "); ?></td>
                                            <td><? echo (" ".$row["adress"]." "); ?></td>
                                            <td><? echo (" ".$row["phone"]." "); ?></td>
                                            <td><a href="view_patient.php">Посмотреть</a></td>
                                            <td><a href="del_patient.php">Удалить</a> <a href="edit_patient.php">Изменить  </a></td>
                                        </tr><?php }; ?>
                                    </tbody>
```

Но на странице в таблице ничего не показывает кроме кнопок посмотреть, удалить, изменить. Самое интересное в таблице столько же пустых строк сколько и в таблице mysql. 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1); тоже молчит. В чем может быть проблема ? Вот так выглядит сама HTML таблица на странице
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

Comment: что показывает var_dump? В исходном коде тоже нет информации, возможно как тег < не воспроизводится.

Comment: `<?` --> `<?php`

Comment: Visman , можно поподробнее ?

Comment: `<td><?` -> `<td><?php` :)

Comment: Visman, наверное я слишком торможу что не понимаю о чем идет речь, 25 раз перепроверил код но так и не нашел ничего по вашему ответу (

Comment: Если вы о коротких тегах то до этого всё работало ведь, на других скриптах

Comment: Действительно всё дело именно в коротких тегах оказывается )) Спасибо Visman )